# Google Maps v2 not showing

Tags: android, maps, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have FragmentActivity responsible for taking pictures and in layout for it I have surfaceView responible for showing camera preview, two more layouts (Layout A and Layout B) that are visible="gone" on start and layout B that has map fragment in it.

When you take a picture, layout A become visible, and you can swicth from it to the layout B. When you do that, map fragment doesn't show up, instead of it you can see camera preview in the area that was intended for tha map. If I than go on some other activity and come back to this one, map is there.

I have one more activity in this app with only map in it and it works fine.

If anyone had this problem please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that SurfaceView and SupportMapFragment both use openGL and if you want to use one of (visible) than you have to remove (gone) the other.